# Where in the Sargauth Level are the paths into Skullport?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, maps, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

In [*Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage) and its Maps and Miscellany, there is a map of the Sargauth level and a map of the levels of Skullport.

Skullport's maps (see [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/skullport#ExploringtheTown) and [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/skullport#32DumathoinsJest)) show the five paths in and out: Shadow Pass, Beggar's Rest Pass, Taglath's Gap, Steamfall Pass and Whisperhaunt Pass.

However, [the Sargauth Level's map](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/sargauth-level#ExploringThisLevel) only shows two paths labelled "To Skullport" how are these paths connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found in an excellent [reddit reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonoftheMadMage/comments/bl8763/the_paths_from_level_3_to_skullport/):

[image: Large Map of Sargauth and Skullport]

> See this map detailing an older version of Undermountain; the mid-east part is definitely Stromkuhldur and the southwest is definitely Skullport. You can see how some of the tunnels connect there in what would be "expanded dungeon" areas, though you could come up with other connections if you like. Note that the passage that runs alongside the Sargauth connects to the south side of Skullport, which doesn't exist on DotMM's Skullport map even though it does exist on the level 3 map (that part does seem like an oversight).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a relatively new GM, I don't know the extended Waterdeep maps and mythology, and I'm mainly using the DotMM hardcover book. (My party is just finishing level 2, and I'm preparing level 3 and Skullport, so I don't know much about the adventure past this point.) But I think I figured out the oversight as referenced by the original poster.

The DotMM book lists five passages to Skullport (book page 303). Four of them appear on the north side of Skullport on the reddit map, and cross-referencing the reddit map with DotMM map #25 (page 307), we can match those four to the Shadow Pass, Beggar's Rest Pass, Taglath's Gap and Steamfall Pass (from west to east). I don't know much about the extended cave network (and I might condense it for my players), but they all seem to eventually lead to area 23 of the Sargauth level (map #3, page 45).

That leaves the southern passage, which must be the Whisperhaunt Pass. I also didn't understand why it was missing from map #25, until I checked the upper level of Skullport (map #26, page 309), where it's located in the southwest corner. So the Whisperhaunt Pass on the upper level is what connects to passage that runs alongside the river.